# Unsuccessful Building the apk file with buildozer

Tags: python, firebase, kivy, buildozer

I am using python, with kivy and json and requests so I can connect it into my firebase.
The program run perfectly fine when I am executing it, but buildozer has some error.

```
/Users/ianlamb/Desktop/PythonProject/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/dists/myapp/gradlew failed!
No setup.py/pyproject.toml used, copying full private data into .apk.
Applying Java source code patches...
Applying patch: src/patches/SDLActivity.java.patch
Warning: failed to apply patch (exit code 1), assuming it is already applied:  src/patches/SDLActivity.java.patch
```

I tried making the spec file with

requirements = python3,kivy==2.0.0rc4, kivymd==0.102.1,requests, urllib3, chardet, certifi, idna android.permissions = INTERNET

I am not sure what the requirements should be.

Thank you!